# GitLab and Dataform integration - wrong commiter's e-mail address

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, dataform

The following setting has to be turned off in GitLab repo in order to enable Dataform’s workspaces git integration in GCP’s GUI:

*Reject unverified users: Users can only push commits to this repository if the committer email is one of their own verified emails.*

If this setting is not disabled, the following error is thrown by Dataform when trying to commit the changes:

```
API request error: Push failed (pre-receive hook declined): GitLab: You cannot push commits for 'dataform+no-reply@google.com'. You can only push commits if the committer email is one of your own verified emails.
```

The actual commits are registered under the user’s e-mail address, but for some reason this is not recognized properly. Since turning this setting off poses a security risk, does anyone know if there's any workaround to allow pushing from Dataform GUI? Did anyone run into a similar issue?

Thanks!